# How to draw - scalable - "EBU safe areas" in ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg, video, preview, ffplay

we need to preview videos with overlayed so-called "safe areas" according to this EBU document: [SAFE AREAS FOR 16:9 TELEVISION PRODUCTION](https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/r/r095.pdf).

Here's the scheme for 1080p resolution:
[image]

Those consist of three different "zones", each with the same percentage size-to-the-edge of the video frame for any resolution:

- **Action Safe Area** (GREEN box): 3.5%
- **Graphics Safe Area** (RED box): 5%
- **4:3 Safe Area** (GREY box): 16.25%

It should be easily achieveable using the *drawbox* command, but how can be dynamically adapted to any video resolution?

Comment: Make a large PNG with transparency, and use that. Use the scale2ref filter to adapt to the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, (driven) ChatGPT did it:

```
ffplay -vf "drawgrid=x=(iw/2):(ih/2):t=3:color=yellow@0.5, drawbox=x=(iw-iw*0.95)/2:y=(ih-ih*0.95)/2:w=iw*0.95:h=ih*0.95:color=red@1, drawbox=x=(iw-iw*0.965)/2:y=(ih-ih*0.965)/2:w=iw*0.965:h=ih*0.965:color=green@1" filename.ext
```